Set a ZD500R 300dpi printer to 203 dpi
I have a ZP505 203dpi printer in production.
I'd like to swap it with another printer, a ZD500R-300dpi.
The issue I'm having is it's printing undersized labels.
Through some research, I've identified the issue as relating to DPI.
The label program I'm running expects 203dpi and this cannot be changed. The program is also opaque to me (3rd party) so I cannot make any modifications on this end.
How would I set the ZD500R to 203dpi?
I've seen a few commands online like ^JMB however this only halves the DPI.
There is also ^Mud but that has to be run every time from what I understand? And ^Mum sets to mm which is fine but I'd need to run this each time too?
I'm very unfamiliar with ZPL.
I can send a command to the printer from the Zebra Utility. Or I can use Windows Printers Printing Preferences to use a custom command before the job prints. My options for 'type' are File, Text, Parsed Text, and Parsed File. Not sure which one to use.
Thanks.

^MUd200,300 is likely the only solution.  The ZD500 does not appear to have an equivalent control panel setting. And unfortunately, it is not a setting that is preserved on power reset.  Can you write a utility to send the command to the printer each time it is power cycled?  I believe you would just need to send ^XA^MUd200,300^XZ, since the ZPL documentation indicates the setting is persisted from label to label.
